# remove horizontal and vertical dotted line in android studio layout preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Every time I hover over layout preview on the new Android studio 2.2.2, it's showing those dotted horizontal lines. Is there a way to disable that?

Snapshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Its a  new feature in android studio from 2.2. its quite handy feature why do u want to disable it?

Comment: Not saying that it is not handy, but it should be configured to be enabled and disabled.

Comment: it's a really headache not a most desired feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, when you hover over the preview layout on your IDE, automatically these dotted lines appears, and once you hover away from the preview (for instance having your cursor on your java or XML class), they disappear.

Comment: but,one small help... when i hover over the preview layout on ide, that time itself. how to hide the dotted line.. can u help me